# BigBlueButton: WebRTC Audio Failure: Error 1010: ICE negotiation timeout

Tags: amazon-ec2, websocket, webrtc, ubuntu-16.04, bigbluebutton

I've setup an Ubuntu 16.04 EC2 t2.medium server and followed the instructions here http://docs.bigbluebutton.org/2.0/20install.html to install BigBlueButton 2.0-beta.

When I log into the Demo Meeting room and select Microphone it says *calling...* then changes to *connecting...* and then I get a message saying:

> WebRTC Audio Failure
>
> Detected the following WebRTC issue: Error 1010: ICE negotiation
> timeout. Do you want to try Flash instead?

Here is the output from the console:

```
BigBlueButton call accepted
bbb_webrtc_bridge_sip.js?v=591:497 Waiting for ICE negotiation
sip.js?v=591:2900 Thu Sep 21 2017 11:27:19 GMT+0800 (WITA) | sip.invitecontext.mediahandler | stream added: fuEOgOt7p5aHrW58wGtGVszgTdGBcNKi
sip.js?v=591:2900 Thu Sep 21 2017 11:27:24 GMT+0800 (WITA) | sip.invitecontext.mediahandler | RTCIceChecking Timeout Triggered after 5000 milliseconds
bbb_webrtc_bridge_sip.js?v=591:499 5 seconds without ICE finishing
bbb_webrtc_bridge_sip.js?v=591:119 Stopping webrtc audio test
bbb_webrtc_bridge_sip.js?v=591:555 Hanging up current session
sip.js?v=591:2900 Thu Sep 21 2017 11:27:24 GMT+0800 (WITA) | sip.inviteclientcontext | terminating Session
sip.js?v=591:2900 Thu Sep 21 2017 11:27:25 GMT+0800 (WITA) | sip.transport | sending WebSocket message: 

BYE sip:919673089@172.31.36.135:5060;transport=udp SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/WSS msk2aa46iuih.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK7275105
Max-Forwards: 70
To: <sip:919673089@staging.bigbluebutton.xxxxxx.com>;tag=SBBF64e6999Hm
From: "w_zqmgpmdukz39-bbbID-Mikhail" <sip:w_zqmgpmdukz39-bbbID-Mikhail@staging.bigbluebutton.xxxxxx.com>;tag=d6e9kj05rj
Call-ID: epjgsffnq2hi688jlvgl
CSeq: 9777 BYE
Supported: outbound
User-Agent: BigBlueButton
Content-Length: 0   



bbb_webrtc_bridge_sip.js?v=591:465 call ended null
sip.js?v=591:2900 Thu Sep 21 2017 11:27:25 GMT+0800 (WITA) | sip.inviteclientcontext | closing INVITE session epjgsffnq2hi688jlvglj9cdnvthcr
sip.js?v=591:2900 Thu Sep 21 2017 11:27:25 GMT+0800 (WITA) | sip.invitecontext.mediahandler | closing PeerConnection
sip.js?v=591:2900 Thu Sep 21 2017 11:27:25 GMT+0800 (WITA) | sip.dialog | dialog epjgsffnq2hi688jlvgld6e9kj05rjSBBF64e6999Hm deleted
sip.js?v=591:2900 Thu Sep 21 2017 11:27:25 GMT+0800 (WITA) | sip.ua | user requested closure...
sip.js?v=591:2900 Thu Sep 21 2017 11:27:25 GMT+0800 (WITA) | sip.ua | closing registerContext
sip.js?v=591:2900 Thu Sep 21 2017 11:27:25 GMT+0800 (WITA) | sip.registercontext | already unregistered
LoggerFactory.print @ sip.js?v=591:2900
LoggerFactory.(anonymous function) @ sip.js?v=591:2917
Logger.(anonymous function) @ sip.js?v=591:2911
unregister @ sip.js?v=591:3579
close @ sip.js?v=591:3570
UA.stop @ sip.js?v=591:8929
(anonymous) @ bbb_webrtc_bridge_sip.js?v=591:505
setTimeout (async)
(anonymous) @ bbb_webrtc_bridge_sip.js?v=591:498
EventEmitter.emit @ sip.js?v=591:115
accepted @ sip.js?v=591:5641
onSuccess @ sip.js?v=591:6851
Promise resolved (async)
receiveInviteResponse @ sip.js?v=591:6832
receiveResponse @ sip.js?v=591:3784
InviteClientTransaction.receiveResponse @ sip.js?v=591:7832
onMessage @ sip.js?v=591:8566
ws.onmessage @ sip.js?v=591:8424
sip.js?v=591:2900 Thu Sep 21 2017 11:27:25 GMT+0800 (WITA) | sip.transport | received WebSocket text message:   

SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/WSS msk2aa46iuih.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK7275105;received=52.51.xx.xx;rport=38902
From: "w_zqmgpmdukz39-bbbID-Mikhail" <sip:w_zqmgpmdukz39-bbbID-Mikhail@staging.bigbluebutton.xxxxxx.com>;tag=d6e9kj05rj
To: <sip:919673089@staging.bigbluebutton.xxxxxx.com>;tag=SBBF64e6999Hm
Call-ID: epjgsffnq2hi688jlvgl
CSeq: 9777 BYE
User-Agent: FreeSWITCH-mod_sofia/1.9.0+git~20170822T213300Z~2ebdf42f2c~64bit
Allow: INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, OPTIONS, MESSAGE, INFO, UPDATE, REGISTER, REFER, NOTIFY
Supported: timer, path, replaces
Content-Length: 0   



sip.js?v=591:2900 Thu Sep 21 2017 11:27:25 GMT+0800 (WITA) | sip.transport | closing WebSocket wss://staging.bigbluebutton.xxxxxx.com/ws
sip.js?v=591:2900 Thu Sep 21 2017 11:27:25 GMT+0800 (WITA) | sip.transport | WebSocket disconnected (code: 1000)
sip.js?v=591:2900 Thu Sep 21 2017 11:27:25 GMT+0800 (WITA) | sip.ua | connection state set to 1
sip.js?v=591:2900 Thu Sep 21 2017 11:27:25 GMT+0800 (WITA) | sip.transaction.ict | transport error occurred, deleting INVITE client transaction z9hG4bK9694442
```

I've searched for anything related to *bigbluebutton error 1010* but can't find anything.

Comment: Seems like this can be a problem: RTCIceChecking Timeout Triggered after 5000 milliseconds. Is it possible to pass different ice server somewhere?

Comment: Not that I know of, I'm very new to BigBlueButton.

Comment: @MikhailJanowski Did you you solve this problem?

Comment: @MikhailJanowski how did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your firewall :

- TCP ports 80, 443,and 1935 are accessible.
- TCP port 7443 is accessible if you intend to configure SSL (recommended), otherwise port 5066 is accessible.
- UDP ports 16384 - 32768 are accessible.
- Port 80 is not in use by another application.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is your sip ip and port.
Check /opt/freeswitch/etc/freeswitch/sip_profiles/external.xml settings firstly.

ws-binding: :5066
wss-binding: :7443
change it to like this:

ws-binding: your_external_ip_address:5066
wss-binding: your_external_ip_address:7443
Your external ip address is same with external_sip_ip address.

Then check your 5066 and 7443 port if you use firewall.

Then dont forget to restart bbb (bbb-conf --restart)